# Disable Eclipse to report "problems" on auto-generated classes (for example Q-classes)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

**Spring Tool Suite 4 Version: 4.19.0.RELEASE**

Is there a way to configure STS4 / Eclipse to stop generating warnings in Problems view for auto-generated classes?

For example: "*Unqualified access to the field QUser._super*".

I don't want to turn of this type of warnings for the whole project or workspace because I want my classes to use qualified access and that warning hepls me except on auto-generated classes.

Below you can see the plugin I use to generate Q classes:

---

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.maven/apt-maven-plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

[image]

Comment: You can invoke the Clean Up functionality at the project or source folder level from inside the Package Explorer view to alter the Member Accesses in those sources.

Comment: @nitind I'm not sure I understand what to do. I go to package explorer, then right click on generated sources folder and then what? Or something else?

Comment: First, go to the **Java** -> **Code Style** -> **Clean Up** preference page, then when you've right-clicked on the source folder, you'll find the **Clean Up...** action in the **Source** submenu.

Comment: @nitind Finally managed to do this. Never ever heard about this cleanup option and few days ago my first attempt to configure it cause the whole project to be broken. Today I tried again and  yes, now it's working exactly as I wanted  / expected. If you put your comment as answer, I'll mark it as accepted. So far I managed to vote up for your comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't perfect, as you'd need to rerun it if you regenerate your sources, but you can invoke the Clean Up functionality at the project or source folder level from inside the Package Explorer view to alter the Member Accesses in those sources. First, go to the **Java** -> **Code Style** -> **Clean Up** preference page, then when you've right-clicked on the source folder, you'll find the **Clean Up...** action in the **Source** submenu.

Answer (score 1):

You could mark the folder of the generated classes as `Derived`.

Comment: But Maven still creates Q classes when Eclipse starts automatic rebuild.

Comment: Yes, the code keeps generating and the code still is problematic. But all the markers from Eclipse regarding this containing generated-classes are gone. You still have warnings for the classes in the `src`-folder but this Derived-flag marks the folder and all its java-files as Derived from other sources (like `src/test/java` and `src/main/java`) that are the root of the problem.